# Filling area of same color in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

im writing application similar to MS Paint, I've got pencil, shapes and line functionality alredy. I'm adding `System.Windows.Shapes.Shape` objects (like Rectange, Ellipse etc.) to Canvas and everything works fine. Now im wondering how to create "bucket" functionality like in MS Paint (filling area of same color), is it possibile to do such thing in my app or i need to refactor it?

Comment: Your question is similar to another post on SO. Here's the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038378/how-to-fill-enclosed-area-in-the-bitmap-object-with-a-color

Comment: @André it's involved almost to gdi bitmap, although we can extract the algorithm there. However the OP seems to wonder if there is any easier approach in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are diffrent ways of implementing this depending on your skill and time.

If i would do it, i would link the pixels that are same color and at the same place by

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling this method. And then color them.

or this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Do you think it would be good idea to convert my canvas to Bitmap, find points of area to fill, and then create polygon from those points and add it to canvas?